# Microsoft Works {Vista} Text to the right of a table

Tags: microsoft-word

I have put in a table in a document and would like to add text to the right/alongside it, but haven't been able to. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Did you mean Microsoft **Works** or Microsoft **Word**? Your title says "Works", but you've tagged the question as "word".

Comment: Oops I've posted an answer thinking it referred to word, because of the tag. Does anyone happen to know if the steps for MS Works is similar? I"m guessing the word processor is much more limited in functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text wrapping of the table to "Around" instead of the default "None". Select the entire table, go to **Table tools > Properties** and choose "Around"

[image]

You can then move your table around and add any text alongside it.

[image]